# How to return all records that were added to the database within the last 7 days from current date

Tags: mysql

I want to return all records that were added to the database within the last 7  days from current date .

I have got events calendar table as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE events_calender (
  company_name varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  reg_date timestamp 
);
```

and i have inserted events till next month as shown below

```
Insert into events_calender values('Childerse Event' , '2013-10-24 18:19:03');
Insert into events_calender values('Womens Event' , '2013-10-27 18:19:03');
Insert into events_calender values('Mens Event' , '2013-10-30 18:19:03');
Insert into events_calender values('DOlls Event' , '2013-11-02 18:19:03');
```

I have got a web service for which i need to feed with the events for this week (7 days from current time)

I have tried with the following query ,

```
SELECT  * from events_calender
WHERE   reg_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

But its not giving any results .

Could you please tell me what might be the cause for which its causing error ??

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3d41/2

Thanks and have a great weekend.

Comment: try this:reg_date BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) )
    AND DATE ( NOW() )

Comment: Your data dates almost two years back - it's not surprising the query returns no data...

Comment: Thanks  still no luck , SELECT  * from events_calender
WHERE  reg_date BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) ) AND DATE ( NOW() )

Comment: your year is 2013 man please check.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25bd0/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this: `use DATE_ADD`
first update the data i.e. `with the 7 day range data`.then use the below `sql`,it should return few records.

```
CREATE TABLE events_calender (
  company_name varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  reg_date timestamp 
);



Insert into events_calender values('Childerse Event' , '2015-10-24 18:19:03');
Insert into events_calender values('Womens Event' , '2015-10-21 18:19:03');
Insert into events_calender values('Mens Event' , '2015-10-27 18:19:03');
Insert into events_calender values('DOlls Event' , '2015-11-29 18:19:03');
```

**sql:**

```
SELECT  * from events_calender
WHERE   reg_date BETWEEN  DATE( NOW() ) AND DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) )
```

Comment: But why it is returning old records (Oct 20th)

Comment: because it comes between the 7 day range from 24th oct.

Comment: Starting from the current day , is it possible to return 7 days upcoming events ??(not the before ones)

Comment: but your question says last 7 days.

Comment: sorry for the confusion but actually i wanted it from current day to 7 days .

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct but problem with the insert command. You are entering the wrong date time , means the data doesn't exists between these dates.

```
Insert into events_calender values('Childerse Event' , '2015-10-23 12:00:00');

Insert into events_calender values('Womens Event' , '2015-10-22 12:00:00');

Insert into events_calender values('Mens Event' , '2015-10-21 12:00:00');

Insert into events_calender values('DOlls Event' , '2015-10-17 12:00:00');
```